# How do you configure Jenkins to automatically install dependencies?

Tags: jenkins, dependencies

I am setting up Jenkins for Python codebase. I have been installing the dependencies directly on the server by hand, but there has to be some way to get Jenkins to automatically install the code's dependencies before it does a new build?

Comment: Presumably you need to automate this process anyway (in order to set up your own environment appropriately), using some kind of script.  Why not just create a Jenkins job that runs that script?

Comment: I think generally dependencies would be installed by build system, either automatically (such as Maven for Java) or explicitly (such as with Makefile rules). Jenkins can run the dependency installation operation, just like any build operation, but I don't think there's any specific support for arbitrary dependency checking.